# How do you deal with CORS when requesting a code to begin oAUTH2 flow?

Tags: jquery, oauth-2.0, canvas-lms, lti

I am trying to get a very minimal proof of concept oauth2 flow going for a web app hosted locally and hitting a cloud oauth provider (Canvas LMS oauth2/LTI).

I need the user to click a button on my initial page (local web app) that starts the process with the external oauth2 server.

If I make the following a clickable link then I get get the user authorization page which, if the user clicks 'accept' provides an authorization code. But I need the authorization code to be available in my javascript, not displayed on a redirect page.

```
<a id='authClick' href='https://XXX.instructure.com//login/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&scope=auth/userinfo&redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth_complete.php'></a>
```

If I use AJAX to make the call, I hit CORS errors - which seem legit and basic web security.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://XXX.instructure.com/login/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth_complete.php",
        processData: true,
        success: function(canvasCode) {
          console.log('Called Canvas - response: ' + canvasCode);
        },
        error: function (data) {
           console.log('Fail - could not get LTI auth token...');
        }
      });
```

I don't understand how you call the auth server and get a code that you can then use (step 2, in javascript or maybe php back end) to obtain a token.

Any help deeply appreciated - I'm close...just missing some crucial core concept (as usual).

Comment: Why do you use the Auth code grant? There is a better option - [the Implicit grant](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2), which is designed for browser apps.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look...

Good question. i'm trying to use the Canvas LMS LTI oauth2 flow...not sure it supports implicit. See https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.oauth.html.

I have kludged together a hidden link (that my javascript clicks) to get around CORS...then redirected to a page that parses the redirect_uri to get the code, then hands it to a backend php script (again CORS) to hit the Canvas server for tokens. Which is working...

Implicit seems much simpler:)